# Building php5.3 with ./configure not creating a Makefile

Tags: php, linux

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, attempting to build and install php 5.3.22. I am unable to build as when I enter 'make' I get:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Doing some research, it means that there is no Makefile, which should have been created when I ran ./configure. I got no error or feedback when running ./configure, nor do I get anything when I run ./configure --help. I'm in the correct build directory, otherwise I would get 'command not found?'

Other solutions suggest running autogen.sh, but I think that's only when you are building from a repo.

I also read that there should be a Makefile.in file somewhere, but I do not see that in the directory.

I just want to be able to properly configure and get a generated Makefile so I can build.

Comment: What do the contents of `configure` look like? Are they what you would expect?

Comment: By the way, do you know that PHP 5.3 is EOL for years now? Also 5.3.29 is the latest version, if you insist on using unsupported software!

Comment: I need this particular version because my magento version is older and doesn't support newer php versions.

Comment: configure is empty. I'm not sure everything is working correctly because I dont get anything with ./configure --help. No errors.

Comment: Well you wouldn't get anything, if the configure command is an empty file. And if you're putting this thing on the internet, you're just inviting all sorts of security and liability problems by using outdated and unsupported software.

Comment: I was assuming that doing ./configure --enable-memory-limit would populate the file? Or do I manually add options to the file? Doesn't explain why --help doesn't work...

Comment: You're running a command. If that command is an empty file, it's not going to be able to do anything. See my answer below.

Comment: You would be much better served by spending your time making your application work with a current version of PHP than trying to resurrect a version that's been EOL for over a year.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the configure script, try running `./buildconf --force`. I've not done this myself but got this by looking at [the source repo](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.3.22) and a couple of Google searches.

> Before you can build PHP you first need to obtain its source code. There are two ways to do this: You can either download an archive from PHP’s download page or clone the git repository from git.php.net (or the mirror on Github).
>
> The build process is slightly different for both cases: The git repository doesn’t bundle a configure script, so you’ll need to generate it using the buildconf script, which makes use of autoconf. Furthermore the git repository does not contain a pregenerated parser, so you’ll also need to have bison installed.

[PHP Internals Book](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/build_system/building_php.html)

Comment: I've downloaded from the php archive. I'll try out your solution